# Is it possible to create an alias to rlogin and pass login paramteres?

Tags: password, alias, putty, autologin

There is a system I need to rlogin to for work, and each time it asks for my username and password and after the login I have to type in a code-word in order to get to the view I want. Is it possible to create an alias that will automate that? I was able to create a login macho with Reflection X, but i want to use putty instead.

Comment: Have a look at [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).  There's [some examples here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/), including a login.

Comment: There are tools to automatize windows application you could use that, but I find it is too complicated. I myself use "Xshell" an ssh client like putty which accepts some scripting like expect on Unix. It is not free for business usage so I don't post it as an answer.

Comment: Are you using the `rlogin` command, or the rlogin protocol with PuTTY?